Use of libnodave.dll in Visual Studio C# project
I am trying to communicate with PLC siemens using libnodave.net.dll
public void Connect()
{
    _connected = false;
    _error = string.Empty;

    string ipAddress = _plcIp + '\0';
    IntPtr ipPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(ipAddress);

    _fds.rfd = libnodave.openSocket(102, "192.168.1.100");
    _fds.wfd = _fds.rfd;

    if (_fds.rfd > 0)
    {
        _fdi = new libnodave.daveInterface(_fds, "IF1", 0, daveProtoISOTCP, daveSpeed187k);
        _fdi.setTimeout(500);

        int error = _fdi.initAdapter();
        if (error == 0)
        {
            _fdc = new libnodave.daveConnection(_fdi, 0, _plcRack, _plcSlot);
            error = _fdc.connectPLC();
        }

        _connected = error == 0;
        if (!_connected)
        {
            _error = daveStrerror(error);
        }
    }

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipPtr);
}

I am new with visual studio c# programming, the project is organized in 2 layers, UI layer project and business project (here i have my plc class for communication). In the UI project (which is set as default project) i instantiate PLC class and call connect method.
But as soon as it tries to open the socket this error is raised "System.BadImageFormatException: 'Tentativo di caricare un programma con un formato non corretto. (0x8007000B)'" which means attempt to load a program with a not valid format.
libnodave.net.dll is inside the project and in my exe path i have also libnodave base dll.
What am i doing wrong?

That is a sign of bitness issues. Presumably the "libnodave base dll" is a 32bit dll but you compile your code for anycpu or excplicitly as 64bit application. As that lib is unmanaged code you must compile your assembly with the same bitness you can't mix bitness.

That seems to be a TCP connection? So, why not use dotnet - canonical TCP? Does that lib have a protocol implemented that you need? Isn't there an implementation of the same for .Net? Maybe it's worthwhile to find one over trying to integrate with unsafe/native code ...

Searching for "Nuget Siemens S7" yields quite a variety of options ...

@Ralf is correct, libnodave.dll is a native x86 library. Specifically, adding <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget> to the .csproj file prevents the BadImageFormatException.

Many thanks @BenHutchison this did the trick

A C#/.NET-Native API would still be way more convenient ... but it's your call.
